# Tensorflow, MultiRNN, why are there so many cells?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to build a sequence to sequence model in tensorflow and I am using the MultiRNN class to chain together 3 GRUs for my encoder.

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as encode_scope:
    encoder_rnn = rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn.GRUCell(1024)] * 3)
    encoder_state = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, encoder_rnn.state_size))
    for t in range(TIME_STEPS):
        encoder_output, encoder_state = encoder_rnn(getTimeStep(input_tensor, t), encoder_state)
        encode_scope.reuse_variables()
```

I am currently viewing my model on tensorboard.  When I expand the encoder node in the graph it looks like this...
[image]

It continues extending to the left until it gets to cell 63.  What exactly are these cells and why are there 63 of them?  I was expecting to see something more like 3 items when I expanded the encoder node (1 for each GRU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `TIME_STEPS`?  Is it perhaps 64?

Comment: It is a constant 64

Comment: You are building a subgraph for each time step. That's why you see those nodes. For a dynamic rnn, see tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()